# Ansible: YAML inventory for staging / production hosts

Tags: ansible

I can't setup inventory which will be easy and useful in `yml` format for Ansible Playbook :(

For example:

```
all:
  children:
    db:
      children:
        production:
          hosts:
            1.1.1.1:

        staging:
          hosts:
            11.11.11.11:

    web:
      children:
        production:
          hosts:
            2.2.2.2:

        staging:
          hosts:
            22.22.22.22:
```

So, I have two playbooks with:

playbook-db.yml

```
...
hosts:
  - db
```

and `playbook-web.yml`

```
...
hosts:
  - db
```

And I want to use this inventory like:

`andible-playbook -D playbook-db.yml --limit=staging`

I am expecting that my playbook will be used only `db` and `staging` hosts, but playbook is applying for all `staging` hosts: `11.11.11.11` and `22.22.22.22` (but I am expecting 11.11.11.11 only) :(

How I can realize it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a misunderstanding about the inventory file, since ansible is doing as you described

```sh
ansible-inventory -i your-posted-file.yml --list
```

emits

```json
{   ...
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "db",
            "ungrouped",
            "web"
        ]
    },
    "db": {
        "children": [
            "production",
            "staging"
        ]
    },
    "production": {
        "hosts": [
            "1.1.1.1",
            "2.2.2.2"
        ]
    },
    "staging": {
        "hosts": [
            "11.11.11.11",
            "22.22.22.22"
        ]
    }
```

showing that the `db` group has all members of `production` and `staging`, but `staging` has hosts `"11.11.11.11", "22.22.22.22"` just as you described

I think perhaps you were conflating the yaml indentation with membership, but that's not how ansible inventories work.

What is far more likely is that you'd want a `db-staging` and `db-production` group, for the case you described where you want only `db` hosts that are `staging`, leaving the `db` group to mean *every* `db` member

Comment: looks like this is the only one way, to do `db-staging` and etc - I tried it before and it worked. Thank you

Comment: It so not intuitive, so what I understand is that I need different hosts files for `production.yml` and `staging.yml` ? and then I can keep simplified group names as `db` and `web` ?